# How to select from MySQL where a SET does not equal a value?

Tags: mysql, set

we have an issue because this is how the table was setup. How do we select from a table where a set does not contain a value? If we have a set with one,two and we do

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column NOT IN('one')
```

we will still get that row. What is the correct syntax for this?

Thanks

Comment: Is one in small letters? NOT IN ('one') won't work on 'ONE' for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what worked:

```
SELECT *, FIND_IN_SET('hidden', props) As hidden
FROM gt_content
HAVING hidden IS NULL
```

Comment: This makes some sense since `[FIND_IN_SET()] Returns NULL if either argument is NULL.` so I'm assuming you `gt_content` allows NULL values, and you are in fact looking for such rows. How about `SELECT * FROM gt_content WHERE FIND_IN_SET('hidden',props) = 0 OR FIND_IN_SET('hidden',props) IS NULL`?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('one',column) = 0
```

Some test I did:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE setTest (s SET('a','b','c','d'));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.60 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO setTest VALUES ('a'),('a,b'),('b'),('a,c'),('c,d');
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.14 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM setTest;
+------+
| s    |
+------+
| a    |
| a,b  |
| b    |
| a,c  |
| c,d  |
+------+
5 rows in set (0.20 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM setTest WHERE FIND_IN_SET('a',s) = 0;
+------+
| s    |
+------+
| b    |
| c,d  |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.12 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM setTest WHERE FIND_IN_SET('b',s) = 0;
+------+
| s    |
+------+
| a    |
| a,c  |
| c,d  |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT * FROM setTest WHERE FIND_IN_SET('b',s) > 0;
+------+
| s    |
+------+
| a,b  |
| b    |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Comment: Hi, doesn't pull up any results.

Comment: You need to give us some more data then. How your table looks like. What values are there, and how you query for them. See the updated answer for example of working code.

Answer (score 0):

From the mysql manual at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html:

Normally, you search for SET values using the FIND_IN_SET() function or the LIKE operator:

```
  SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE FIND_IN_SET('value',set_col)>0;
  SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE set_col LIKE '%value%';
```

The first statement finds rows where set_col contains the value set member. The second is similar, but not the same: It finds rows where set_col contains value anywhere, even as a substring of another set member.